# Offline Fairplay AVAssetDownloadTask got unknown error callback while downloading (only happened on iOS 10.2)

Tags: ios, swift, fairplay, avassetdownloadtask

We're building offline fairplay content for our client app; we implemented that feature by referencing to Apple sample download manager AssetPersistenceManager class in HLSCatalog demo app.
There is one function, and two call back in AssetPersistenceManager class that I want to highlight here, it's

```
    /
    func downloadStream(for asset: Asset) {
        /
         For the initial download, we ask the URLSession for an AVAssetDownloadTask
         with a minimum bitrate corresponding with one of the lower bitrate variants
         in the asset.
         */
        guard let task = assetDownloadURLSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset.urlAsset, assetTitle: asset.name, assetArtworkData: nil, options: [AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey: 265000]) else { return }

        /
        task.taskDescription = asset.name

        activeDownloadsMap[task] = asset

        task.resume()

        var userInfo = [String: Any]()
        userInfo[Asset.Keys.name] = asset.name
        userInfo[Asset.Keys.downloadState] = Asset.DownloadState.downloading.rawValue

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: AssetDownloadStateChangedNotification, object: nil, userInfo:  userInfo)
    }
```

And callback when it's finished downloading the stream

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    /
     This delegate callback should only be used to save the location URL
     somewhere in your application. Any additional work should be done in
     `URLSessionTaskDelegate.urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)`.
     */
    if let asset = activeDownloadsMap[assetDownloadTask] {

        userDefaults.set(location.relativePath, forKey: asset.name)
    }
}
```

The last is didCompleteWithError callback

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask,
didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
```

Everything seems works fine on iOS < 10.2, but after test on some device which running latest iOS 10.2, the app alway got callback to didFinishDownloadTo delegate while only 13-15% completed percent, after that the 
    didCompleteWithError
is called and we received below error

```
> "=======> completed percent 11.2888760669556" .
> "=======> completed percent 11.44566601233" 
> "=======> completed percent 11.7592459030787"
> "=======> completed percent 12.0728257938275" 
> "=======> completed percent 12.5431956299506" 
> "=======> completed percent 13.0135654660738" 
> "=======> completed percent 13.3271453568226" 
> "=======> completed percent 13.6407252475713" 
> "=======> completed percent 13.9543051383201" 
> "=======> completed percent 14.1110950836945" 
> "=======> completed percent 14.2678850290689" 
> "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not
> be completed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could
> not be completed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred
> (-12667)}"
```

Checking with the proxy debugging app, it points out that app closes the connection before entire receive response.

```
Status
Complete
Failure
Client closed connection before receiving entire response
Response Code
206 Partial Content
```

Only iOS 10.2 has that error, the same stream tested on other OS below that version is still working fine.
Trying to find some changelog for iOS 10.2 about this part but I found nothing? Do you guys have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found out the answer ourself after a week stucking with it. It turned out to be bugs on iOS 10.0 - 10.1 instead of 10.2.
The error occurs after 30s is related to DRM error, it happened on iOS 10.2, after AVAssetDownloadTask are resumed there is a callback from AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate and you need to hit server key to fulfill the Fairplay DRM content key in

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, 
shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool
```

Otherwise, download will be forced to stop and you will receive unknown error as mentioned above.
Apple sample code HLSCatalog is just demo for non-DRM stream, and they didn't even mention about the content key fulfillment required in the demo.

We have followed their sample and seem iOS 10.0 - 10.1, AVFoundation didn't check the content key on processing download, that's the reason why when we first implementing our Download feature, we thought content key isn't needed when downloading, that lead us to a wasteful week on stucking in iOS 10.2...

Comment: Do you guys know if using Fairplay is mandatory for using AVAssetDownloadTask with encrypted HLS? I get the same error although I implement the `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` callback and deliver a local encryption key. It works fine while streaming, but the download always fails with the above error. So I was thinking that it might be an issue with not using Fairplay!? Or could you provide me with your implementation of the key handling inside `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource `? Maybe I'm doing sth wrong.

Comment: I think you should try to hit your server key to get a new key in shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource instead of using 'local encryption key'. The local key aka 'persistent key' will not be able to use for re-downloading nor airplay streaming.

Comment: @VadimNikolaev are you trying to playing a downloaded offline content ? in that case the resourceLoader was called to asking for the persistent key that should have gotten when you start the download task previously, that key should be stored locally (e.g: UserDefault) in order to use when app in offiline

Comment: @untouchable Would there be a reason we are seeing `Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=skd://`. We are using a 3rd-party player/download sdk and we often get this error, which results in the license not being downloaded. We use the sdk wrapped in a flutter plugin. But since we don't own the code, what would be the best way to debug?